# Evaluate $\frac{1}{a}\int_0^\infty{x^2}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2a}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Evaluate the following integral:
$$\frac{1}{a}\int_0^\infty{x^2}e^{-\large\frac{x^2}{2a}}\,dx.$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $~k=\dfrac1{2a}\quad=>\quad I(k)~=~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-kx^2}~dx\qquad=>\qquad I'(k)~=~-\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-kx^2}~dx$.

But the value of $~I(k)~$ can easily be computed using that of the [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral), with the help of one simple substitution. Then all that's left is to differentiate the result with respect to *k*, and replace it with its expression in terms of *a*.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{2}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2a}}dx=-\int_{0}^{\infty}x(e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2a}})'dx$$

Use integration by parts and the value of Gaussian integral to evaluate:

$$=-(xe^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2a}})\vert_{0}^{\infty}+\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2a}}dx=\sqrt{2a}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2a}})^{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a}}dx=\sqrt{2a}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

Alternatively notice that:

$$-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{a\pi}{2}}=\frac{d}{db}(\sqrt{\frac{2a}{b}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2})\vert_{b=1}=\frac{d}{db}(\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{bx^{2}}{2a}}dx)\vert_{b=1}=-\frac{1}{2a}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{2}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2a}}dx$$

Comment: please elaborate your answer , I cant understand it. I try to do by part but cant proceed

Comment: $\int_{0}^{\infty}x(e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2a}})'dx=xe^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2a}}\vert_{0}^{ \infty}-\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2a}}dx=-\sqrt{2a}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Without using the gamma function. With the same method usally used to compute the Gauss integral, but without using the Gauss integral itself :

[image]

(A typing mistake corrected)